# How to keep key in redis if it's being used, and expire if not?

Tags: caching, redis

I have a specific cache system in Redis.

The content of this system is quite volatile, and values get added and removed all the time. I want to keep the "used" keys in memory as much as possible, while getting the old ones to expire.
Each request can require hundreds of keys from the cache.

I'm aware that I could set a "long enough" expire time, and just dealt with the Cache misses, but I'd like to have as little misses as possible.

Currently I'm doing something like this, when I'm writing / reading to the cache (pseudo code)

```
# write
write(key, value)
expire(key, ttl)

# read
read(key)
expire(key, ttl)
```

I can optimise the read by using pipelining.

Now this still seems like it's not the best way of doing it.
Could someone give me a better strategy?

Comment: I think your current approach is the best one. From http://redis.io/commands/expire -> Refreshing expires,  *It is possible to call EXPIRE using as argument a key that already has an existing expire set. In this case the time to live of a key is updated to the new value.*

Comment: It is precisely what you are supposed to do (but be sure to use pipelining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is a perfect LRU cache (Least Recently Used), you can tune Redis to behave like this globally, here is a link about Redis as LRU:
http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html

Note that it is using maxmemory property on redis and the eviction rule is global unless you look at volatile LRU: [How to make Redis choose LRU eviction policy for only some of the keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370278/how-to-make-redis-choose-lru-eviction-policy-for-only-some-of-the-keys)

You are using a manual solution for eviction with custom expiration / TTL which is the most powerful solution, but maybe you can simplify your configuration and have a better predictable cache in memory size with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with the (current) resolution of 10 seconds then the [OBJECT IDLETIME](http://redis.io/commands/OBJECT) command would let you get a better sense of what has not been used for a while (in blocks of 10 seconds)

```
> SET X 10
OK
> OBJECT IDLETIME X
10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a script (https://redis.io/commands/script-load) that does this atomically and faster directly on the server side and then use it with EvalSha (https://redis.io/commands/evalsha).

This saves the extra round trip on each of the commands.

Alternatively you can implement a similar algorithm to the LRU cache that Redis runs when it's out of space (https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) - every once in a while get random keys and remove them if they're too old for you, optionally loop until you get a long sequence of new keys.